# Norms for which every subset of closed unit ball containing the open unit ball is convex

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

It can be shown  without much difficulty that any Euclidean norms satisfies  the following condition :$$(P) \quad B \subset X \subset B' \Rightarrow X \, \text{is convex}$$ 
where $B=\{x \in E / \|x\| <1\}$ and $\overline B=\{x \in E / \|x\| \leq 1\}$ are respectively the unit open and closed ball of the Eulidean space  $(E,\|.\|)$.

I asked myself if $(P)$  is a characterization of Euclidean norms  but, looking I found a counter-example.

This is on $\Bbb R^2$: $\displaystyle N(x,y)=\sup_{t \in \Bbb R} \frac{|x+ty|}{1+t+t^2}.$

**My questions:**

1) is there any studies about the norms satisfying the condition $(P)$ ?

2) I want others counter-examples with norms whose expression is less complicated than the above counter-example.

Comment: $$\lVert x\rVert_p = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert x_k\rvert^p\right)^{1/p}$$ for $1 < p < \infty$. The Euclidean norm is the case $p = 2$. Generally, you need a norm that is "strictly convex", meaning that the boundary of the unit ball contains no line segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer noted, condition (P) is equivalent to the norm being [strictly convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_convex_space).

Indeed, if the norm is not strictly convex, then the unit sphere contains a line segment, and removing the midpoint of this line segment from the closed unit ball creates a nonconvex set.

Conversely, if the norm is strictly convex, then any $X$ as you described is convex, since all interior points of any line segment with endpoints in $X$ belong to $B$ and therefore to $X$.